# LEFT JOIN Query not giving expected output

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database

**Motivation:** I'm designing an access database to track my employee's training status. Each employee has a training requirement based on their role (e.g. admin assistants must take records management training and telephone etiquette whereas electricians must take hazardous safety). I want to be able to generate a report that shows, for each person, all training required, and for those training courses that are completed, the date they were completed.

**Schema** I have the following tables:

- Personnel -- lists employees info, e.g. name, telephone, email; key: `PersonnelID`
- Courses -- lists all courses available and gives a description; key: `CourseID`
- Roles -- lists all work roles in the company (e.g. electrician, admin assistant); key: `RoleID`
- LnkPersonnelCourses -- records show that `PersonnelID` completed `CourseID` on `CompletionDate`
- LnkPersonnelRole -- records show that `PersonnelID` was assigned to or removed from `RoleID` with effective date `EffectiveDate`
- LnkRolesCourses -- records show that `RoleID` requires `CourseID`

I created a query **`qryPersonnelCourseRequirements`** to match `PersonnelID` to the required courses for their current `RoleID`:

```
SELECT qryLastLnkPersonnelRoleAddOnly.PersonnelID, LnkRolesCourses.CourseID 
FROM qryLastLnkPersonnelRoleAddOnly INNER JOIN LnkRolesCourses 
    ON qryLastLnkPersonnelRoleAddOnly.RoleID = LnkRolesCourses.RoleID;
```

This works correctly and tells me each individual's current training requirements:

[image: TrainingRequirements]

Here is a snapshot of the **`LnkPersonnelCourses`** table which shows which of the courses each person has completed and when (data is notional).

[image: LnkPersonnelCourses Table]

**Problem:**
When I try to match the individual's training records recorded in `LnkPersonnelCourses` to the training requirements in the above query, it only shows that the individual completed a single course, when in fact, the individual has already completed multiple courses that satsify their training requirements. I've attempted the query several ways. Here's as close as I have gotten:

```
SELECT pcr.PersonnelID, pcr.CourseID, lpc.CompletionDate
FROM qryPersonnelCourseRequirements AS pcr LEFT JOIN LnkPersonnelCourses AS lpc 
    ON (pcr.CourseID = lpc.CourseID) AND (pcr.PersonnelID = lpc.ID);
```

[image: LEFT JOIN with pcr]

and

```
SELECT lpc.PersonnelID, lpc.CourseID, lpc.CompletionDate
FROM qryPersonnelCourseRequirements AS pcr LEFT JOIN LnkPersonnelCourses AS lpc 
    ON (pcr.CourseID = lpc.CourseID) AND (pcr.PersonnelID = lpc.ID);
```

[image: LEFT JOIN with lpc]

**Desired behavior:**

I would like the query to produce the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with both your query was you were comparing `PersonnelID` of `qryPersonnelCourseRequirements` table with `ID` of `LnkPersonnelCourses` table but you were suppose to compare it with  `PersonnelID` of `LnkPersonnelCourses` table to get the desire output.

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    pcr.PersonnelID, pcr.CourseID, lpc.CompletionDate
FROM 
    qryPersonnelCourseRequirements AS pcr 
LEFT JOIN 
    LnkPersonnelCourses AS lpc On 
    (pcr.CourseID = lpc.CourseID) AND (pcr.PersonnelID = lpc.PersonnelID );
```

This should produce the desired result.

Comment: Perfect diagnosis -- I edited your original answer so that `PersonnelID` and `CourseID` had to come from the `pcr` query. Now this works exactly as intended. Thank you!